# Convert GPS data to latitude and longitude c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, gps, converters

I have a GPS device(gt003) which sends data to my server, I need to convert the **01E0598A 0869058A** values that the device sends into latitude and longitude.

Latitude

Occupy 4 bytes, representing the latitude value.

Number range is from 0 to 162000000, which represents the range form 0°to 90°. Unit: 1/500 second Conversion method:

A) Convert the latitude (degrees, minutes) data from GPS module into a new form which represents the value only in minutes;

B Multiply the converted value by 30000, and then transform the result to hexadecimal number

For example22°32.7658′,（22×60＋32.7658）×30000=40582974, then convert it to hexadecimal number 0x02 0x6B 0x3F 0x3E

Longitude

Occupy 4 bytes, representing the longitude value of location data. Number ranges from 0 to 324000000, representing the range form 0°to 180°.Unit: 1/500 seconds, Conversion method is the same as latitude’s.

Expected output close to **17°29'20.2"N 78°23'21.7"E**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

01E0598A(16) = 31480202(10).

Divide by 30000 -> 31480202 / 30000 = 1049.34006666. As you mentioned, it is value in minutes. 
So: 1049.34006666/60 = 17.489001°(If you need decimal of degrees - that is it). What is 17°. 
0.489001° -> 0.489001 * 60 = 29.34". So 29". 0.34 least. 0.34 * 60 = 20.4'. 
Result = 17°29"20.4'.

The same for 0869058A:

```
0869058A(16) = 141100426(10).
141100426 / 30000 = 4703.347533333333".
4703.347533333333 / 60 = 78.38912555555556° -> 78°
0.38912555555556 * 60 = 23.3475333333336" -> 23"
0.3475333333336 * 60 = 20.852000000016' -> 20.85'
```

Result: 78°23"20.85' = 78.38912555555556°

Comment: its giving degrees and minutes.how can I get seconds and lat value like 17.488885.

Comment: I gress you are the GT06 Tracker, how do you figure out if the coordinate is to south or north, east or west? I'm trying to make a server for the same protocol using Node.js
Thank you.

Comment: according to documentation for concrete tracker. S and W as positive and N and E as negative or vice versa.